# rpart in R: variable in formula

Tags: r, rpart

I'm using a decision tree on textual data and I stored the n most frequent terms in a variable and I try to use this variable in the formula for the `rpart` function. However, the error I get is the following:

`Error in model.frame.default(formula = class ~ x, data = dtm.df, na.action = function (x): variable lengths differ (found for 'x')`

```
x = findFreqTerms(dtm, 0.5)
fit = rpart(class ~ x, data = dtm.train
```

Is it possible to fill in the formula automatically without having to manually type every feature?

Comment: From the sample code you provide it is obviously the formula that is the problem here. As is noted in the [R documentation on formula class](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html), "Such a model consists of a series of terms (...). The terms themselves consist of variable and factor names (...). Such a term is interpreted as the interaction of all the variables and factors appearing in the term.". First, no variables are used here for the regression; secondly since `x` doesn't comprises all the factors of the class appearing in it, it throws you an error.

Comment: How should rpart be used on textual data then? What comes after the `~` should be words from the document term matrix, no?

Comment: Could you provide us a sample of the data you want to classify ? After the `~` you need variables names or a `.`, like such `class~Variable1 + Variable2 + Variable3` or like `class~.` .

Comment: I used this example: http://web.letras.up.pt/bhsmaia/EDV/apresentacoes/Bradzil_Classif_withTM.pdf (check page 14, they put the 20 most frequent words after the `~`). So basically I have exactly the same, but I want to know if there's a way to not type every word manually after the `~`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Technical basis for the solution**

The idea behind what you would like to achieve is to create the formula from the most frequent terms used, which are strings.

The broad idea is to create the formula from the variable instead of using input text as in my comment (*i.e.* directly writing `class~Variable1 + Variable2 + Variable3` ).

[This link provide an example on how to use a string to create a formula](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Formulas/Creating_a_formula_from_a_string/), and you will also need to look at the `collapse` argument of the `paste()` [function in R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html).

**Code**

```
# First find your most frequent terms
x <- findFreqTerms(dtm, 0.5)

# Then prepare the variables for the formula
sMeasureVar <- "class"
sGroupVars  <- paste(x, collapse = " + ")

# Create the formula from the variables
fRpart <- as.formula(paste(sMeasureVar, sGroupVars, sep=" ~ "))

# Fit the tree associated
fit <- rpart(formula = fRpart , data = dtm.train)
```

Comment: This works like a charm. However, there is one problem: it doesn't work if you use bigrams, i.e. features of a document are always 2 words. The formula would then look like this: class ~ a b + c d + e f (if you type it like this it says "unexpected symbol"). Do you have any idea how the formula should look like if you use bigrams (or even trigrams)?

Comment: I found the problem: I just had to put each terms between backticks. Thanks!